# Building a firebase app without angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'd like to build a firebase web app.  Most examples seem to recommend using angular with firebase, and the angular-fire bindings in particular.

I don't use Angular and it seems like unnecessary overhead.  My understanding of firebase is that it provides a simple JS API, where you setup callbacks and handle the events to update the dom, which could presumably be jquery.  Since firebase is using a broadcast/web socket approach to send changes to my app, I'm not sure if I would need angular's 2 way binding all that much.

So, do i or should i use Angular with firebase or not?  Will I run into issues with $scope and angular's lifecycle of events?  I'm also concerned about the major changes coming with Angular 2.

Comment: You're asking *several* different questions here:  whether or not you can use Firebase without Angular, what issues you'd run into *with* Angular, and whether or not it'd work out with Angular 2.  Could you narrow it down a wee bit?

Comment: What are the advantages of using angular with a real time backend like Firebase?

Comment: Can Firebase be used without Angular? Certainly. Here's a 5 minute tutorial of using Firebase without AngularJS: https://www.firebase.com/tutorial. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web is also full of examples without AngularJS. Whether you should do so and a warranty that you won't have issues are beyond the scope of StackOverflow.